# i'm creating a color game , how can i update the variable in run() method?

Tags: java, runnable, actionevent

```
package myPackage;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Random;

public class Colorgame extends Applet implements Runnable , ActionListener{

boolean starter = true;

public void init(){
        this.setSize(800, 650);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(Color.pink);
        myFont = new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,20);
        new Thread(this).start();

        //button
        start = new Button("Start");
        start.setBounds(370, 610, 50, 30);
        start.addActionListener(this);

        add(start);
}


public void run(){
        while(starter){
        try{
            ranColor = rand.nextInt(6);
            switch (ranColor) {
            case 0:
                dieColor = Color.red;
                Thread.sleep(100);
                repaint();
                break;
            case 1:
                dieColor = Color.blue;
                Thread.sleep(100);
                repaint();
                break;
            case 2:
                dieColor = Color.green;
                Thread.sleep(100);
                repaint();
                break;
            case 3:
                dieColor = Color.yellow;
                Thread.sleep(100);
                repaint();
                break;
            case 4:
                dieColor = Color.orange;
                Thread.sleep(100);
                repaint();
                break;
            case 5:
                dieColor = Color.magenta;
                Thread.sleep(100);
                repaint();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(dieColor);
    g.fillRect(355, 90, 80, 80); //colour die
}
```

and this button starts/stops the random changes of the colour die but when i clicked the button the boolean `starter` becomes "false" but in the run() method it never changes

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            if(e.getSource() == start){
                if(starter == true){
                    starter = false;
                    start.setLabel("Stop");
                }
                else if(starter == false){
                    starter = true;
                    start.setLabel("Start");
                }
    }
```

Comment: I know you might think that this is not related, but it is: Please try to use code formatting to organize your code. The code will get much more readable. Most current Java editors can automatically apply a code style for you. When the code is more readable, there is a better chance of you finding the problematic code sections.

Comment: Sorry sir.. I'm new here so I'm trying to cope up. By the way, thanks for the advice

Comment: Don't worry. This was not a complaint, but an advice for your programming. It is better to start as early as possible with the organisation of code. It also increases the learning speed. Readability (and sometimes maintainability) is more important than most people think. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are using 2 different threads to access the same local variable. In Java, each thread can cache the value of the variable for itsef. To prevent this, declare your variable as volatile:

```
volatile boolean starter = true;
```

See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: uhm.. what does 'volatile' do? Sorry, i'm average in java

Comment: “… the volatile modifier guarantees that any thread that reads a field will see the most recently written value.” - Josh Bloch

Comment: It basically makes sure that a thread doesn't see an invalid value that might be caused when accessing the value while another thread is in the middle of rewriting the value.

Comment: there's a problem.. when i press the start button, the colour die stops making the boolean 'starter=false' and changes it's label to "stop" but when i'd clicked the button with a label "stop", the variable 'starter' becomes 'true' but colour die stops its randomization

Comment: @KimInopia that's because you returned from `run`.

Comment: @immibis isn't the run() does update like every second? like update() method in unityscript..

Comment: @immibis ohh.. so instead of using run().. then what method should I use runs like an update?